# Weighting feature by time

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, weights

### Context

In the price elasticity of demand modeling field.

I have some data to use, which the basic is average weekly price and volume of a product.  As you can see in the image, each point represents the weekly value of transactions.

The goal is to weight values in order to give importance to more recent value. According to a business solution resource, it was proposed to fix this by weighting, so as to help the model fit and better interpret these relationships.

In other words: "More recent observations weigh more" is how it looks on the left graph.

[image]

### Question

With this contextual framework I ask myself:

What transform/weighting do you think is interesting and how would it be applied to the data series?

In this case the exponential weighting is proposed.

Comment: I don't really like this idea. at least in a max likelihood framework (as opposed to least squares), weighting denotes confidence. why not rather add time variation to your coefficients.

Comment: @seanv507 If applied in a linear regression model? Could you elaborate more this so we have a response on this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea is often proposed.
Here is one previous question
[Justification for using geometric weights in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10806/) which has an interesting response by @whuber

In a least squares sense, there is nothing wrong with weighting errors higher for more recent events.

However, it doesn't seem to make sense in a maximum likelihood framework eg in applying significance tests, where the weighting is related to confidence, eg repeated counts or accuracy of measurement.

If you believe the data is changing over time, then use a time varying model. This could be as simple as adding a time interaction with your other variables.

This way you use the data most efficiently, since you are not downweighting earlier data.

Perhaps if you want to go down the weighting approach, you could try to estimate the residuals. Eg estimate with one month of data and track how the residuals change as you predict each previous month. ( The squared residuals would be your empirical weighting curve)

If you saw a trend in the residuals though, I would be inclined to add time to the model to capture the trend rather than allow for increased error.